# Curl -d : Contents of the file must be URL Encoded

Tags: python, json, curl, flask

I have an app running in `Python` using `Flask`.

The endpoint of the `API` looks like this:

```
@app.route('/postIt', methods =['POST'])
def postReview():
    #print flask.request
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        posts  = flask.request.get_json()
        print posts
    return str(posts)
```

I am trying to send it request using `CURL`:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/postIt -d @post.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

where `post.json` looks like this:

```
{"post1":"3", "post2": "2", "post3":"3", "post4":"4" "post5": "5"}
```

This is not working well. Output on server side prints nothing implying that it is unable to get the json file that I am sending.

I looked into `-d flag of CURL` and found this thing:

```
The contents of the file must  already  be URL-encoded.
```

So I am guessing there must be `encoding issues with my post.json` file. I don't exactly know which encoding should be used here. Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried your code, I got `400 Bad Request`:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Then I found that your json file is actually not valid. There is a missing `,` between `post4` and `post5`. After fixing it, I got the correct response:

```
{u'post5': u'5', u'post4': u'4', u'post3': u'3', u'post2': u'2', u'post1': u'3'}%
```

Comment: what is the % at  the end of your json?

Comment: That's zsh's output for something doesn't ends with newline.